# How to "catch" if I click on an other TAB from a specified TAB in HTML, jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, tabs

My HTML code:

```
<div id="tabsWithStyle">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#data1">Data 1 TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#data2">Data 2 TAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#data3">Data 3 TAB</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="data1">
    <jsp:include page="./data1.jsp" flush="false"></jsp:include>
</div>
<div id="data2">
    <jsp:include page="./data2.jsp" flush="false"></jsp:include>
</div>
<div id="data3">
    <jsp:include page="./data3.jsp" flush="false"></jsp:include>
</div>
```

My JQUERY code, which can tell me the number of the TAB which had been selected/clicked:

```
$('#tabsWithStyle').tabs({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        var activeTabNumber = $( "#tabsWithStyle" ).tabs( "option", "active" );
        alert("number of selected tab link: "+activeTabNumber);
    }
});
```

I want to know, if I was on the data2 link, and then I click on an another link. How could I "catch" it? I hope I could express myself well enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YYTkr/1/)

### HTML

```
<div class="tab">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected" data-value="first">testing</li>
        <li data-value="second"><a>testing1</a></li>
        <li data-value="third"><a>testing2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="first">first</div>
    <div id="second">Second</div>
    <div id="third">Second</div>
</div>
```

### Script

```
$.fn.GTtab = function() {
    this.find('li').css('cursor','pointer');                        
    var show=this.find('li.selected').attr('data-value');
    $('#'+show).show().siblings().hide();
    this.find('li').on('click',function(){
       show=$(this).attr('data-value');        
       $('#'+show).show().siblings().hide();
    });

};
$( ".tab" ).GTtab();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the `ui` parameter of the `activate` event handler contains everything you need:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

- newTab: The tab that was just activated.
- oldTab: The tab that was just deactivated.
- newPanel: The panel that was just activated.
- oldPanel: The panel that was just deactivated.